# How to get a relation between tables in MYSQL with Python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database

Good morning!

I know that with the following query:

```
query = '''
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = database_name
'''
```

I can get all the columns of all the tables in a database. My question is: is there a way in which I can get the relations, using code through Python, between the columns of different tables?

Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: in short you shouldn't be using the information_schema.column view to generate dynamic SQL for JOINing, you should do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but my objective is to get that information in order to create a Graphviz graph to visualize relations in the database.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent mysqlworkbench functionality?

Comment: Well i don't know your naming convention..  if you use for example  `product(id, name)` and `category(id, product_id)` or `product(product_id, name)` and `category(category_id, product_id)`  ...  The second case might make it a little bit more easy  as you can use `GROUP BY column_name HAVING COUNT(<DISTINCT> table_name) >= 2` to find possible relating columns.

Comment: @P.Salmon I didn't know about mysqlworkbench, but yes, I want to do a little software that replicates that functionality, so I could add functionalities that I would need on my own. Do you know how I can get that information?